# Joining two RDDs column in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

This is the already asked question but I could not understand the answers properly.

I have two RDDs with same number of columns and same number of records

```
RDD1(col1,col2,col3)
```

and

```
RDD2(colA,colB,colC)
```

I need to join them as following :

```
RDD_FINAL(col1,col2,col3,colA,colB,colC)
```

There is no `key` to perform a join between records but they are in order which means the first record of RDD1 is corresponded to first record of RDD2.

Comment: RDD doesn't preserve internal order of rows. Your question is quite broad to answer frankly. Please make some efforts reviewing your question !

Comment: Also please read on how to ask question on SO ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @eliasah thank you for respond and guide...actually these two rdds come from two different text files...the only thing i need is to combine all the columns...one of the reason is to compare "col1 and colA"... i wanted to try the join operation ,however my data set does not have any identity key like primary key in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `zipWithIndex` method to add the index of the row as a key to both RDD's, and join by it by the key.

Comment: this is the useful answer but i cant rate it because i do not have enough reputation .... thank you @Alfilercio

Answer (score 1):

Adding code snippet for Alfilercio's example.

```
JavaRDD<col1,col2,col3> rdd1 = ...
JavaPairRDD<Long, Tuple3<col1,col2,col3>> pairRdd1 = rdd1.zipWithUniqueId().mapToPair(pair -> new Tuple2<>(pair._2(),pair._1());

JavaRDD<colA,colB,colC> rdd2 = ...
JavaPairRDD<Long, Tuple3<colA,colB,colC>> pairRdd2 = rdd2.zipWithUniqueId().mapToPair(pair -> new Tuple2<>(pair._2(),pair._1());

JavaRDD<Tuple2<Tuple3<col1, col2, col3>, Tuple3<colA,colB,colC>>> mappedRdd = pairRdd1.join(pairRdd2).map(pair -> pair._2());
```